# Yii2: How to let ActiveRecord models only see certain database data?

Tags: activerecord, model, yii2, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement a multi-tenant application. I have different customers that are using the same code. But each customer gets its own entry script with its own configuration. The customer id is accessible by `Yii::$app->params['customerId']`. Note: I have to distinguish the customers that way because there is no login/authentication. Anyway, assume the controller action is called and a customer id is given with the parameter.

Now I have some tables and each has a column for the customer id. I have created model classes with gii and all is fine. But now I've got the problem that I have to check or tell for each database operation which customer id has to be used. So on every db operation (Query) I can add an `->andWhere(['customerId' => Yii::$app->params['customerId']])`. This is tedious and error prone, of course.

Is there a way to simplify this? Consider that there are find, insert, update, delete and join operations. I can probably use [Customized query classes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes) but I don't know what I have to do there and I'm not sure if it helps with inserts/updates/deletes. Consider also that there are related tables with the same customer id colum. `hasMany()` and `hasOne()` should also reflect this.

My aim is to have the customer id be as transparent as possible. I don't want to think about it. So I could imagine some kind of abstract query class that uses a certain column (the customer id column) for all operations and that gets the customer id somehow (injected or with `Yii::$app->params['customerId']`).

My assumption is that I need to do this mainly in the model. I think controllers are less concerned by this topic.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In situations like the ones you described a form solution it is to manage data with database views able to filter the data for customer id. This involves dynamic access to the tables / views that you can manage through changing function tableName () of the model. Creating views can also be automated with functions DML database. This is only a brief introduction i hope this is useful for you.